# Proposition 5.17 on Rudin's RCA

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying Proposition 5.17 on Rudin's RCA.
The proposition is here:

Let $V$ be a complex vector space.
(a) If $u$ is the real part of a complex-linear functional $f$ on $V$, then
$$f(x)=u(x)-iu(ix)$$ for all $x\in V$.
(b) If $u$ is a real-linear functional on $V$ and if $f$ is defined by the expression in (a), then $f$ is a complex-linear functional on $V$.
(c) If $V$ is a normed linear space and $f$ and $u$ are related as in the expression in (a), then $\|f\|=\|u\|$.

I could understand the proofs of (a) and (b), but I could not understand the proof of (c).

Here is the proof of (c):
Since $|u(x)|\leq|f(x)|$, we have $\|u\|\leq\|f\|$. On the other hand, to every $x\in V$ there corresponds a complex number $\alpha$, $|\alpha|=1$, so that $\alpha f(x)=|f(x)|$. Then
$$|f(x)|=f(\alpha x)=u(\alpha x) \leq|u||\alpha x|=\| u\|\cdot\| x \|$$ which proves that $\|f\|\leq\|u\|$.

Note that Rudin defined
$$\|f\|=\sup \{|f(x)|\ \colon x\in V, \|x\|\leq1\}.$$

My questions are here:

1. I cannot understand why $f(\alpha x)=u(\alpha x)$ holds.
   It is sufficient to show that the real part of $f(i\alpha x)$ is zero by the expression in (a) because $f(\alpha x)=u(\alpha x)-iu(i\alpha x)$. And I tried to calculate the real part of $f(i\alpha x)$, i.e., $u(i\alpha x)$, but it didn't work.
2. Also I do not know why $u(\alpha x) \leq\|u\|\cdot\|\alpha x\|$ holds.
   My attempts are here:
   Since $f$ is linear by the assumption, then $\alpha u(x)=u(\alpha x)$ holds (I suspicious this is a mistake). Then I use the fact if $L$ is a linear transformation, $$\|Lx\|\leq \|L\|\cdot\|x\|$$ holds (see page 96 in Rudin's RCA). Note that this fact only depends on the homogeneity of linear function.

Comment: $u$ is the real part of $f.$ Therefore if $f(y)$ is real, then $f(y)=u(y).$ Since $f(\alpha x)=|f(x)|,$ $ f(\alpha x) $ is real. Therefore  $f(\alpha x)=u(\alpha x).$

Answer (score 1):

We know that
$$|f(\alpha x)|=f(\alpha x)=u(\alpha x)-iu(i\alpha x)$$
The LHS is a non-negative real number. But then the imaginary part of the RHS has to be $0$, i.e. $u(i\alpha x)=0$, which yields what you want. Note that $u$ being real valued is relevant here.

Comment: I understand your answer. I've added a question and would appreciate if you could answer it.